# MICOM 3F VR1 part

Tags: resistors, identification, radio

[image]

It is marked with a circle and ON in the middle. then you can see SR wrapping around the sided but the bracket is in the way from there. on the other side you see 467 SK0 but then the oppisite bracket is in the way.  Can anyone help? this is in a MICOM 3F radio and the bord is marked VR1. there is a 2nd one on the board marked VR2.  I thought with those markings it would be a Varriable Resistor but I am having no luck finding a replacement. Note to everyone out there: if it requires 13.8 VDC, dont send 48 VDC.

Comment: This is a good example of why we post pictures. ON = ON semiconductor formerly Motorola